# HTML Spinner to only stop when all images have uploaded?

Tags: html, jquery

Sorry I didn't get a notice that someone had replied to my message :( but I solved the issue by changing the code to:

which now means the spinner runs until all the images are fully loaded

Thanks for your replies

Tim

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//Preloader
preloaderFadeOutTime = 5000;
function hidePreloader() {
var preloader = $('.spinner-wrapper');
preloader.fadeOut(preloaderFadeOutTime);
}
hidePreloader();
```

---

I have lots of images on my HTML page which is using a preloader spinner but at the moment the spinner stops before all the images on the page has fully uploaded.

Is there a way to make the spinner to continue until all the images have uploaded so when you click on the search button the preloader show straight away.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
//Preloader
preloaderFadeOutTime = 500;
function hidePreloader() {
var preloader = $('.spinner-wrapper');
preloader.fadeOut(preloaderFadeOutTime);
}
hidePreloader();
}); 
</script>
```

[preloader screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U459P.png)

[lots of images on web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVYiU.png)

This show how the spinner is not working
http://www.tc-design.co.uk/spinnertest/testspinner2.html

Hope you can advise, please?

Comment: Uploading exactly how? We need to see how the images get uploaded in order to tie up a spinner with the existing source code. Does the upload return a promise?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. At least in your demo page it seems you want to show multiple images with a preloader on the foreground and hide it when all are done loading, right?